# Why do services provide a list of recovery codes for two factor authentication instead of just one?

Tags: security, two-factor-authentication

The title pretty much says it all. I am currently implementing two factor authentication and wonder whether I should provide a list of recovery codes. I wouldn't even have thought of it myself, but most implementations I have seen in the wild do it this way. Github for example generates a list of 16 recovery codes at once.

Is there any security benefit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Great question - I'm pretty sure it's an ease of implementation thing for both parties - if you generate a list of recovery codes up front then you don't have to regenerate a code every time a user uses a backup code. The idea is that the user will print/save them somewhere so from a usability perspective this saves the user from having to re-print or re-save codes.

You don't have to use recovery codes, though. GitHub supports a [few different recovery options](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa/recovering-your-account-if-you-lose-your-2fa-credentials). Some companies use security questions or allow you to fall back to SMS.
Some companies make you call support and provide account details (works for enterprise use cases where there's a trusted contact/if you expect to have a small number of account recovery cases/have a good way of [verifying identity over the phone](https://www.twilio.com/blog/best-practices-security-inbound-contact-center) [disclaimer I wrote that post for Twilio]).

I [gave a talk about this last year](http://site-622572.bcvp0rtal.com/detail/video/6185106929001/designing-customer-account-recovery-in-a-2fa-world) and have some more [recommendations in the slides](https://www.slideshare.net/KelleyRobinson1/identiverse-2020-account-recovery-with-2fa). Hope this helps!

Comment: Turns out recovery via trusted contacts is no longer supported by Facebook:  https://www.facebook.com/help/119897751441086?cms_platform=www&helpref=platform_switcher